# Why doesn't this function's while loop run on infinitely?

Tags: c

Hello people I have this example from a power point slide and I don't seem to understand why the while loop in the function only happens once. The way I interpret it is that it will go on forever, but apparently it doesn't.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 481;
    int b = 910;
    int result = 0;
    result = gcd(a, b);
    printf("%d\n", result);
    return 0;
} 

int gcd(int a, int b)
{
    while(b!=0)   // HERE IS MY PROBLEM!, Wouldn't this while loop go on forever?
    {
        int tmp = b;
        b = a% b;
        a = tmp; // how could 'a' be 13 if tmp is 0, at beginning they do tmp = b(0)
    } 
    return a;
}
```

I just don't get it... it says while b doesn't equal 0, and our b is 910, so it's never going to be 0 which means the while loop never ends does it now? Also in the function tmp=b which is 0 and THEN they modify b, but even if they modify b temp is still 0 because b was originally 0 before being modified..Confused here..

EDIT:
I made error, saying tmp = b will always be 0, was looking at b's value from inside function and forgot b was 910 from outside.

Comment: This is trivially easy to understand if you debug it. What I just don't get is why you won't debug. Add some `printf` statements inside the loop. You should also enable warnings and deal with them.

Comment: I will try that inf unction.

Comment: What @DavidHeffernan said, or just step through the loop in your debugger a few times to see what is really going on?

Comment: I will try this statement in fucntion,   printf("%d", b);

Comment: What's important here is not what is happening, but learning how to debug. Once you do that you can answer these questions yourself. Imagine how liberating that would be.

Comment: nvm it didn't work, it just gave me this huge number

Comment: @user3718584: it wasn't a huge number - you just forgot to include a `\n` in your `printf` format string.

Comment: "Also in the function tmp=b which is 0", tmp would never be zero!

Comment: Hmm.. it does go to 0. but it goes from 481, 429, 52, 13 and then finally 0.. hmm >.。

Comment: Note that debug printing statements, in particular, should normally end with a newline `'\n'` (or, more accurately, `"…\n"`) so that the output appears in a timely manner.

Comment: @user3718584: If you haven't yet, please read [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Your comments are weird. They don't "do tmp = b(0)". `b` starts off as `910`. `tmp` is never `0`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, I just made edit and explained for my error in misreading it

Comment: It's easy to understand where those numbers come from if you understand division.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop runs more than once, and each time the loop runs, the value of b will be less than the previous iteration because (a % b) is an integer in the range [0, b), which is exclusive of b.

On the first iteration:
a = 481, b = 910

For the second iteration:
b = a % b => 481
a = 910

For the third iteration 
a = 481
b = (910 % 481) = 429

tmp will never be 0 because if b is 0, then the loop stops and 0 will not be assigned to tmp.

Answer (score 2):

Note first that the variables `a` and `b` are passed to `gcd()` by value.  That means that the local variables (parameters) `a` and `b` in the function `gcd()` are unrelated to the variables `a` and `b` in `main()` except by coincidence of naming.

Within the function, before the loop, the values are:

```
a = 481    b = 910
```

Since `b` is not zero, the loop is executed:

```
a = 481    b = 910
tmp := 910
b := 481 % 910 := 481
a := 910
```

and then the loop checks again, and `b` is still not zero:

```
a = 910    b = 481
tmp := 481
b := 910 % 481 := 429
a := 481
```

and the loop repeats again because `b` is still not zero:

```
a = 481    b = 429
tmp := 429
b := 481 % 429 := 52
a := 429
```

and again:

```
a = 429    b = 52
tmp := 52
b := 429 % 52 := 13
a := 52
```

and a final time through the body of the loop:

```
a = 52     b = 13
tmp := 13
b := 52 % 13 := 0
a := 13
```

and now `b` is zero, so the loop terminates, and the value in `a`, which is `13`, is returned.

Note that the values of `a` and `b` in `main()` are unchanged.  You could demonstrate this with:

```
printf("GCD(%d, %d) = %d\n", a, b, result);
```

which is a better output in that it identifies the input values as well as the result.

Answer (score 2):

If you work through each iteration yourself, you'll find that it does indeed terminate:

Iteration 1:
a == 481
b == 910

Iteration 2:
a == 910
b == 481

Iteration 3:
a == 481
b == 429

Iteration 4:
a == 429
b == 52

Iteration 5:
a == 52
b == 13

Iteration 6:
a == 13
b == 0  <-- TERMINATES

Feel free to ask if it doesn't make sense just yet.